# Minimize distance between a line and a point

Tags: calculus, optimization

---

**PROBLEM:**

We want to minimize the distance between a fixed point $(t_0,x_0)$ with $t_0 \leq 0$ and a line, $t = 0$.
Formalise this problem as a Lagrange problem. Solve this equation by the Euler equation.

---

**My approach:**

Obviously, $x(t_0) = x_0$ and we want to minimize the distance of the curve between $(t_0,x_0)$ and $(t_1,x_1)$ where $t_1 = 0$ and $x_1$ is free.

The formula for the length of the graph of a function between two points is the following:

$\int_{t_0}^{t_1} (1 + (x')^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}dt$

Then I have to minimise this distance but I am not sure how to do this.

My intuition says the following:

Euler equation:

- $\frac{\delta}{\delta t}L_{x'}(t) + L_x(t) = 0$
- Since $x_1$ is free we know by the transversality condition that $L_{x'}(t_1) = 0$
- $L$ is the objective function here
- So know we have to solve this and we will get an answer

---

Can somebody please tell me if I am correct?

Answer (score 1):

We want to minimize the function $\;f(x,y):=(x-t_0)^2+(y-x_0)^2\;$ subject to the condition $\;x=0\;$ , which is the same as asking what's the distance between the above given point and the $\;y$-axis, and the answer is, of course, $\;|t_0|\;$, but with Lagrange we get

$$H(x,y,\lambda):=(x-t_0)^2+(y-x_0)^2-\lambda\cdot 0$$

$$\begin{align*}H'_x&=2(x-t_0)=0\iff x=t_0\\H'_y&=2(y-x_0)=0\iff y=x_0\\H'_\lambda&=0\end{align*}$$

and the answer is straightforward.

Comment: thank you very much, but why did you add $y$?

Comment: Where *exactly* did I add $\;y\;$ ?

Comment: the problem consisted first of a $t,x$ plane, where the horizontal axis was $t$ and the vertical axis is $x$. But you added a $y$ in your objective function, am i right?

Comment: First, your notation is pretty strange: why did you choose $\;x_0\;$ as the $\;y$-coordinate of your function is beyond my comprehension, but I am using $x\,,\,y\,$ as generic names for the $\,x\,,\,y$-coordinates, respectively, in the plane. The function $\;f\;$ above is the general distance (squared) function from the given point to **any** other point in the plane, and then comes the condition $\;t=0\;$ , which means we want to focus on the straight line $\;\{(0,y)\;;\;y\in\Bbb R\}\;$